# How to get clipboard data in non main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, clipboard

I'm trying to get data from Clipboard with the below code.

```
private void TestBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Thread sampleThread = new Thread(SampleMethod);
 sampleThread.IsBackground = true;
 sampleThread.Start();
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
 var textFromMain = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
}

private void SampleMethod()
{
 var textFromThread = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

I'm getting whatever text copied to clipboard with this line -

`var textFromMain = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);`

But below line returns empty string or blank string.

`var textFromThread = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);`

I'm not getting what's the issue. Can somebody help me to understand. If it's multi-threading, please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally used below method to access Clipboard text.

```
private string GetClipboardData()
    {
        try
        {
            string clipboardData= null;
            Exception threadEx = null;
            Thread staThread = new Thread(
                delegate ()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        clipboardData= Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        threadEx = ex;
                    }
                });
            staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            staThread.Start();
            staThread.Join();
            return clipboardData;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to make it more out-of-the box: using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms; and GetClipBoardData (not Borad)

Answer (score 5):

`Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)` use COM and throws **exception** if called in thread which not marked with `STAThreadAttribute`.

One way to solve is use delegate to return call of `Clipboard.GetText` to main thread with Invoke. But in this case thread will freeze it execution on Invoke till the `SampleMethod()` ends it execution on main form thread and main thread will be free.

Other way is to use own call to COM to get clipboard text instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText()`, see `ClipboardCom.GetText()`, this method not need waiting main form thread.

```
    private string _textFromMain, _textFromThreadByInvoke, _textFromThreadByCom;

    private delegate string GetClipboardInvoke(TextDataFormat textformat);
    private void SampleInvokeMethod()
    {
        GetClipboardInvoke invokerClipboard = new GetClipboardInvoke(Clipboard.GetText);
        _textFromThreadByInvoke = (string)this.Invoke(invokerClipboard, TextDataFormat.Text); // where this is a Form
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread sampleInvokeThread = new Thread(SampleInvokeMethod) { IsBackground = true };
        sampleInvokeThread.Start();

        Thread sampleComThread = new Thread(SampleComMethod) { IsBackground = true };
        sampleComThread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        _textFromMain = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
    }


    private void SampleComMethod()
    {
        _textFromThreadByCom = ClipboardCom.GetText();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public static class ClipboardCom
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData(uint uFormat);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool IsClipboardFormatAvailable(uint format);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseClipboard();
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(IntPtr hMem);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GlobalUnlock(IntPtr hMem);

        const uint CF_UNICODETEXT = 13;

        public static string GetText()
        {
            if (!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT))
                return null;
            if (!OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero))
                return null;

            string data = null;
            var hGlobal = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
            if (hGlobal != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var lpwcstr = GlobalLock(hGlobal);
                if (lpwcstr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    data = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(lpwcstr);
                    GlobalUnlock(lpwcstr);
                }
            }
            CloseClipboard();

            return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'm ended up with another shorter way. Adding it to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me.

```
        Thread theThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            var selectedPodcastPlaylist = (PodcastPlaylist)metroGridPodcastPlaylist.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            Clipboard.SetText(selectedPodcastPlaylist.URI);
        });

        try
        {
            //set STA as the Open file dialog needs it to work
            theThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            //start the thread
            theThread.Start();

            // Wait for thread to get started
            while (!theThread.IsAlive) { Thread.Sleep(1); }

            // Wait a tick more (@see: http://scn.sap.com/thread/45710)
            Thread.Sleep(1);

            //wait for the dialog thread to finish
            theThread.Join();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
```

Inspired by the article and source from here
[Thread Apartment Safe Open/Save File Dialogs for C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/841702/Thread-Apartment-Safe-Open-Save-File-Dialogs-for-C)